# Read Lines Depending on Value in Following Lines

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to do a calculation based on the content of a line, but only if another line in the same document satisfies specific criteria. The order of the lines is not consistent.

A file might look like this:

```
Line A: 200
Line B: 200
Line C: 5
```

So an example condition would be, if Line C is 6 or greater, add the value from Line A "200" to a counter.

I have tried a variety of `if` statements, and also tried setting a `BOOL`. I haven't been able to get either to work. An excerpt of my latest attempt follows:

```
    counter = 0
    good = True
    
        for line in text:
                line = line.strip()
                if line.startswith('Line C') :
                    rtime = re.findall('[0-9]+:[0-9]+', line)
                    for t in rtime:
                        if t < 6 :
                            good = False
                            print("-----To Small. Ignore Line A")
                            break
                        else :
                            good = True
                            
                while good == True :
                    if line.startswith('Line A') :
                        numstring = re.findall('[0-9]+', line)
                        for num in numstring:
                            temp = float(num)
                            counter = counter + temp
        
                    else : continue
                           print("----- good must be False. Should be ignoring Line A")
```

Answer (score 1):

First, read all the rows from the file into a dictionary so that you have:

{'Line A':200, 'Line B':200, 'Line C':5}

After this it is easy to apply the criterias with conditionals like "if value['Line A'] > 6:" etc.

I am leaving with you the implementation of this because it sounds a bit homework-y. Let me know if you need more help!

Comment: I realize this is probably a newbie question, but it is not school homework. I am not a programmer by education, but am trying to solve a workplace problem by learning Python. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a dictionary if the lines aren't too long. A simple way would just add the lines to a dictionary and then check your condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

allDataLines = []
allQualifierLines = []
dataFileName = 'testdata.txt'
def chckForQualifierLine(line):
    # lines containing qualifier
    if not line.startswith('Line C'):
        return False
    # do more checks here, if not good just return False
    
    allQualifierLines.append(line)
    return True

def chckForDataLine(line):
    # lines containing data    
    if not line.startswith('Line A'):
        return False
    # do more checks here, if not good just return False
    
    allDataLines.append(line)        
    return True

with open(dataFileName, 'r') as text:
    # Further file processing goes here
    line = text.readline()
    while line != '':
        #print(line, end='')
        if not chckForQualifierLine(line):
            chckForDataLine(line)
        line = text.readline()
    for qualifierLine in allQualifierLines:
        # this line is valid qualifier
        print(f"Q: {qualifierLine}")
        for dataLine in allDataLines:
            # do with data line(s) what ever is to do here
            print(f"D: {dataLine}")
```